# C memory leak with fsanitize=address

Tags: c, pointers, makefile, memory-leaks

I am trying to write a bit of code to create a sorted linked list and insert only unique elements in such a way that the linked list will remain sorted. Also, I implemented a function to delete a node with a given value and one to print it.

I have a few testcases that have to be run, and the testing piece of software requires the main.c file and a makefile, and in the makefile I am required to use fsanitize=address.

Without it, the testcases pass, but with it included in the makefile, the code will exit with the message

> "SUMMARY : AddressSanitizer: 64 byte(s) leaked in 4 allocation(s)."

or something similar. It shows that some are direct leaks, some are indirect leaks.

Here is the **updated code** that I've written.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* Link list node */
struct Node {
    int val;
    struct Node* next;
};

void ins(struct Node** head, struct Node* node, int* len) {
    // check if the val held by the head is equal to the new node's val
    // if it is, return
    if(*head != NULL && (*head)->val == node->val) {
        free(node);
        return;
    }

    /* Special case for the head end */
    if (*head == NULL || (*head)->val > node->val) {
        node->next = *head;
        *head = node;
        // increase the length
        (*len)++;
        return;
    } else {
        struct Node* current = *head;
        /* Locate the node before the point of insertion */
        while (current->next != NULL && current->next->val <= node->val) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        // if the node's val is equal to the val of the node
        // in which position it should be inserted, return
        if(node->val == current->val) {
            return;
        }
        // add the node into the linked list
        node->next = current->next;
        current->next = node;
        // increment the list's length
        (*len)++;
    }
}

// delete the value from the linked list
void del(struct Node **head, int value, int* len) {
    // Store head node
    struct Node* temp = *head;

    // If head node itself holds the value to be deleted
    if (temp != NULL && temp->val == value) {
        // change the head
        *head = temp->next;
        // decrease the length
        (*len)--;
        // free the memory and return
        free(temp);
        return;
    }

    struct Node* prev;
    // Search for the key to be deleted, keep track of the
    // previous node as we need to change 'prev->next'
    while(temp != NULL && temp->val != value) {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    // If key was not present in linked list, return
    if(temp == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    // delete the node from the list
    prev->next = temp->next;
    // decrease length
    (*len)--;
    free(temp);  // Free memory
}

void printList(struct Node *head, int len) {
    printf("%d :", len);
    struct Node *temp = head;
    // print the list's content
    while(temp != NULL) {
        printf(" %d", temp->val);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    /* Start with an empty list and a temporary node */
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    struct Node* temp;
    int len = 0;

    char c;
    int value;
    // while the input is valid
    while(1) {

        // check that there is still input
        if(scanf(" %c", &c) != 1) {
        break;
        }

        // break out of the loop if the first character is other than i and d
        if(c != 'i' && c != 'd') {
        break;
        }

        // read the value
        if(scanf("%d", &value) != 1) {
        break;
        }

        // do the required operations
        if(c == 'i') {
            temp = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            // put in the val and set the next to null
            temp->val  = value;
            temp->next =  NULL;
            ins(&head, temp, &len);
        } else if(c == 'd') {
            del(&head, value, &len);
        }

        // print the list
        printList(head, len);
    }
    free(head);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried fixing some memory leaks, but seems like there still are. My best guess is I'm allocating memory for some pointers in the ins() function and not freeing the memory after using them... I tried freeing memory after using some pointers but that would result in another issues with the code.

Edit : here are some images with the inputs used and the actual "errors" that I get.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note that the third example has no memory leaks and will pass the testcase.

Comment: When you quit the program, you do not free up the nodes that are still in the list.  Could this be the source of your problem?  If not, can you add some sample input that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, indeed, instead of returning from the loop I break and free the list after the while and freeing the head. However, there are still memory leaks. I will update the code now and upload the inputs I'm using.

Comment: `free(head)` only frees the head, not the whole list.

Comment: @melpomene you saved me.. that was quite dumb of me. I thought it would free the entire thing but I actually had to go through each element and free it separately. Thank you so much! No more leaks now.

Comment: I cannot see the pics. Please post text as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What does -fsanitize=address do?

**-fsanitize=address** (this seems like to be an alternative to valgrind, although I'm not sure to what extent) detects memory leaks and reports it after the program exits.

Without this flag (-fsanitize=address) there is no check for memory leaks; this explains why the tests passes without summary of memory leaks when the program is compiled without the flag.

### What Causes The Leaks?

Here in the program, there are 2 reasons for memory leak.

#### First Reason

If the program exits after inserting some elements and without explicitly deleting (calling *del()* on each element) the inserted elements, it causes memory leak.

Example:

```
i
99
i
101
i
100
q
```

Fix: In *main()*

```
if(c != 'i' && c != 'd') {
// external inject
    temp = head;
    while(temp) {
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
        temp = head;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Second Reason

If the same element is inserted twice, the second insertion fails (uniqueness property is maintained) but allocated memory is not freed, it causes memory leak.

Example:

```
i
99
i
99
d
99
q
```

Fix: In *ins()*

```
if(*head != NULL && (*head)->val == node->val) {
    // external inject
    free(node);
    return;
}
.
.
.
if(node->val == current->val) {
    // external inject
    free(node);
    return;
}
```

More about [-fsanitize=address](https://lemire.me/blog/2016/04/20/no-more-leaks-with-sanitize-flags-in-gcc-and-clang/)